# self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES do not pop back to the root

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have this line of code to pop back to the root menu when clicking the "back" button on the top bar:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I have had no problem with this until now, i still use IOS 5.1 as target.

As i run this code now (XCODE 5) i get the following message:

```
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
```

...and it only seems to pop the text in the top bar back to the root (Menu) while the display only pop's back one level. As this has always worked i am a bit puzzled and would like some advice how to solve this. The View Controller were i execute this code is a normal ViewController.

I use `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"xxxxx" sender:self];`to push the ViewControllers.

Just for testing i used this code:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

...and it did pop the VC and then directly pop'ed back to the rootVC without the messages???

Here is the structure, it is from the green VC i have problem going back to the first VC. Again, i have not had this problem prior to xcode5:

[image]

Comment: It *might* work in `viewDidDisappear`.

Comment: Try calling `[super viewWillDisappear:animated];` after popping to root view controller or rather not calling it at all as if one transition is in progress, the other one might not kick in.

Comment: I have tried both answers already, "viewDidDisappear" will pop it back one level at the time and not directly to the root. @Yas Kuraishi Not calling super, or do it after, no difference. The strange thing is that it did work prior to Xcode 5 :-(

Comment: Are you using a previous transition first? I mean are you popping or dismissing a modal view controller before calling this?

Comment: @Lefteris no, I am using "push" via segue.

Comment: use NO: [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I just noticed you are trying to pop to root, when the user pushes back, but here is what is happening:

The OS is trying to push to the previous viewController with an animation and in the same moment, you are initiating a second transition and ask it to pop to the root view controller.

The easiest approach would to replace the system's back button with a custom button that will use your own IBAction and you will then pop to the rootViewController:

First hide the back button:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

and then create your own custom back Button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backBtn =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(popToRoot:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=backBtn;
```

Finally you pop to the RootViewController:

```
- (IBAction)popToRoot:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender {
   [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Remember to remove the `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` from the `ViewWillDisappear` delegate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it still doesn't work. I did put a breakpoint in the navigationBar module but it looks like it is never called. I did add the delegate.

Comment: ...but the weird  thing is that this have worked for two years.

Comment: Ok, please see the new approach. This should be easier to use, the previous one would require to subclass the UINavigationController and would be much more complicated.

Comment: How do you do this but keep the back arrow that you'd normally have with your navigation item?

Answer (score 0):

try this code it will help you..

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

Comment: I did test it and put it in "viewWillDisappear" and it did not work, the same result as the previous ones.

Comment: objectAtIndex:0 it navigates index 0 view controller