# What is wrong with the segue and NavigationController navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, segue, xcode5

This is a continuation/alternative of this thread: [popToRootViewControllerAnimated problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365260/self-navigationcontroller-poptorootviewcontrolleranimatedyes-do-not-pop-back-to) to sort out what is the problem/mistake in a more structured and easier to understand way.

When pressing the back button in VC3 i want to go back to VC1.

I have the following setup:

[image]

The following code:

VC1:

```
@implementation ViewController
- (IBAction)myButton1:(id)sender {

//Call InformationViewController for Quick Game
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toVC2" sender:self];


}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

VC2:

```
@implementation nrTwoViewController
- (IBAction)myButton2:(id)sender {
//Call InformationViewController for Quick Game
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toVC3" sender:self];

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

VC3:

```
@implementation nrThreeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


@end
```

I only pop to VC2, not the root (VC1), and get the following message when pressing back button on VC3:

```
2013-10-15 08:36:08.479 segueTest[44153:a0b] nested pop animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
2013-10-15 08:36:08.831 segueTest[44153:a0b] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
```

I also tried, as suggested, adding the UINavigationBarDelegate:

```
@interface nrThreeViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationBarDelegate>
```

...and:

```
- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item {
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
return NO;
}
```

The result:

> pop'ed from VC3 to VC2 only with no messages in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is where you placed the `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` the error message is `Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state.`  This is because when viewWillDisappear is called, the view is already beginning to transition off the screen, you are then calling another transition.  Try putting it in a button action that simply pops to the root view controller and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: thanks for your comment, that is indeed the solution. More details how to do it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365260/self-navigationcontroller-poptorootviewcontrolleranimatedyes-do-not-pop-back-to